# CDF of Z = max ( 0, X-M )

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, function

I'm trying to understand how the cumulative distribution function of a Random Variable which is a maximum function can be obtained. If $Z = \max(0,X-m)$ where $X$ is another Random variable ( Claim amount ) and $m$ is a pre-defined constant , i have been told that the CDF , $F(z) = P(X-M \le 0)$ for $z = 0$ or $P( 0<X-m < z)$ for $z \ge0 $.

I can't find an intuitive explanation as to why that's the case and am currently stumped. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The second bit is P ( 0 < X - m < z ) for z greater than or equal to 0

Comment: First, $X-m$ is a random variable, so you might as well call *it* $X$ for simplicity.  Second, what you appear to have been told looks like the definition of a CDF, so could you please tell us what you understand the CDF to be?

Comment: Do you mean in general or in context to the Q ? In general if F(x) is a CDF, i believe it is the probability of the Random Variable taking up a value less than or equal to x . In relation to my post, im struggling as to how the max function is treated and what situations it creates  which is throwing me off.

Comment: Work two separate cases: figure out the value of the CDF for any $x\le 0$ and then figure it out for any $x \gt 0.$

Answer (score 1):

$Z$ cannot take on values strictly less than $0$ regardless of what $X$ is: if $X \leq m$ so that $X-m \leq 0$, then $\max(0,X-m)=0$ while if $X>m$ so that $X-m>0$, then $\max(0,X-m) = X-m > 0$. We conclude that for any $z<0$,
$$F_Z(z) \stackrel{\Delta}{=} P(Z \leq z) = P(\emptyset) =0.$$
On the other hand, 
$$F_Z(0) \stackrel{\Delta}{=} P(Z \leq 0) = P(Z=0) = P(X \leq m) = F_X(m).$$
Finally, for any $z > 0$,
$$F_Z(z) \stackrel{\Delta}{=} P(Z \leq z) = P(X-m \leq z) = F_X(m+z).$$
This doesn't seem to match "what you have been told" and so take it with a large grain on salt.

Note that the last two displayed equations can be combined, allowing us to write
$$F_Z(z) = \begin{cases} 0, & z < 0,\\F_X(m+z), & z \geq 0.\end{cases}$$
Note that if $F_X(m) > 0$, there is a "jump discontinuity" at $z=0$ where the value of the CDF "jumps" from $0$ for $z < 0$ to $F_X(m)$ at $z=0$.

Comment: Didn't you intend to write "$P(Z\lt z)$" at the outset rather than "$P(Z\le z)$"?

Comment: @whuber I don't think I meant to write $P(Z<z)$ anywhere. Could you please point out where you think that a "$P(Z \leq z)$" should more correctly read "$P(Z < z)$"? The CDF of $Z$ has a jump discontinuity at $0$ and I clearly stated that $F_Z(z)$ has value $0$ when $z < 0$ whereas $F_Z(0)$ has value $F_X(m)$, that is, there is a discontinuity at $z=0$ and the value of the CDF is the upper value (the value from the right).

Comment: You're right--I misread your statement.  Sorry about troubling you (+1).

Comment: Thank you - appreciate your help !